# How to make a 'group of paths' a Graphic Style (for background)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, background, graphic-styles

I have made these multiple rhombi objects, arranged them in a pattern, now I want to save it as a **Graphic style** so that I can use it as a **background**, I don't know which process to follow, merely dragging it in the **graphic styles panel** isn't working, I'm stuck.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* don't really mean "style".. all you need is a **Pattern Swatch**.

Draw a section..

[image]

Select that and drag it to the **Swatches Panel**. This will create a new **Pattern Swatch**. To refine that swatch, double-click it in the panel...

[image]

You can then adjust the tile size and other options. When you're happy click the `Done` button at the top of the document window.

Then merely draw any object and click your new Pattern Swatch...

[image]

The [**Adobe Help Files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/create-edit-patterns.html) may be of further assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am highly grateful to you.

Comment: You solved a big problem of mine.